# Routing all POST request to 1 APIController method which receives the POST body

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm trying to configure a single method in my ApiController to handle all POST requests, regardless of the number of path segments, and to receive the post body which is always json.  I've tried several variations of wildcard table and attribute routing but can't get it to work for requests with more than 1 path segment.

Also, I can't figure out how to receive the entire json body in the method.

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class MyController: ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("*")]
    public string PostHandler([FromBody]string jsonBody)
    {

        var requestPath = Request.RequestUri.LocalPath;

        return jsonBody;
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like a x/y problem. what are you going to do w/ that?

Comment: Without answering your specific question, I'd note that this is a highly unusual design and sort of flies in the face of everything RESTful. REST defines a series of resources, each at a given endpoint. You are trying to create one endpoint for every resource.

In this case, it would help if you could explain what design problem you are actually trying to solve. Maybe there's a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: I understand the concern about the design. Just experimenting with WebApi at the moment and comparing it to what I'm already doing with HTTPHandlers.

Comment: Try defining the route as `[Route("")]` on action method.

Answer (score 1):

Try using regex wildcard in [Route()] and don't specify [RoutePrefix].
Also try taking the body directly from the request as string, this should work.

```
public class MyController: ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/{*[a-zA-Z]}")]
    public string PostHandler()
    {
        string result = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;   
        var requestPath = Request.RequestUri.LocalPath;

        return result;
    }
}
```

If you want to work with async try this code:

```
public class MyController: ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/{*[a-zA-Z]}")]
    public async Task<string> PostHandler()
    {
        string result = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();   
        var requestPath = Request.RequestUri.LocalPath;

        return result;
    }
}
```

***EDIT***

In `[Route("api/{*asd}")]` the `{*[a-zA-Z]}` part doesn't do anything, rather the MVC stack validates each route with the regex:

```
{(?<parameterName>.+?)(:(?<constraint>.*?(\(.*?\))?))*(?<defaultValue>\?|(=.*?))?}
```

Using [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester) tool i found out that [a-zA-Z] is part of the parameterName group and gets used as injecting values into action parameters.

If we use

```
public class MyController: ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/{*path}")]
    public string PostHandler(string path)
    {
        string result = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;   
        var requestPath = Request.RequestUri.LocalPath;

        return result;
    }
}
```

and call /api/user/123/orders/100, then:

```
path = "user/123/orders/100" 
requestPath = "/api/user/123/orders/100"
```

Comment: Could you explain why this works for the path http://localhost/api/user/123/orders/100 without modifying the regex to include 0-9 ?

Comment: I have no idea, but I intend to see the source to figure out why it works and I'll write back to you

Comment: I found out why is that and edited my answer. Best regards